# Ionic-vue menu breaks after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I created a `Header` component that has a `IonMenu` component in it for a reusable header across pages. The menu is tied to the `IonRouterOutlet` as the docs suggest but its giving me an issue when navigating between pages. Once I navigate between pages, it breaks the click event on the menu button and I can never get the menu to open again unless I do a refresh on the page(F5), what's the issue here?

Once on the homepage(/dashboard) the menu works fine. If I open the menu and then click the `Profile` link I move to that page and the menu again works fine. Once I click the back arrow to move back to the homepage, the menu no longer works.

[Code Sandbox example here](https://45p5xp.csb.app/)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" />
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from "@ionic/vue";
</script>
```

Header.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button defaultHref="/" />
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="end">
        <slot>
          <ion-menu-button />
        </slot>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <HeaderMenu color="primary" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonHeader,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonButtons,
  IonMenuButton,
  IonBackButton,
  IonButton,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import HeaderMenu from "./HeaderMenu.vue";
</script>
```

HeaderMenu.vue

```
<template>
  <IonMenu side="end" content-id="main-content">
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar color="primary"></IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent>
      <IonItemGroup>
        <IonList class="ion-no-padding">
          <IonMenuToggle>
            <IonItem class="ion-text-center">
              <IonButton
                expand="full"
                fill="clear"
                size="small"
                @click="navigate('dashboard')"
              >
                <span>Dashboard</span>
              </IonButton>
            </IonItem>
            <IonItem class="ion-text-center">
              <IonButton
                expand="full"
                fill="clear"
                size="small"
                @click="navigate('profile')"
              >
                <span>Profile</span>
              </IonButton>
            </IonItem>
          </IonMenuToggle>
        </IonList>
      </IonItemGroup>
    </IonContent>
  </IonMenu>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonMenu,
  IonMenuToggle,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonItemGroup,
  IonIcon,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import router from "../router";

const navigate = (routeName: string) => {
  router.push({ name: routeName });
};
</script>

<style>
/* This fixes the issue with the menu not being clickable */
.menu-content-open {
  pointer-events: unset !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky bug in Ionic. It's been around for a long time and they still haven't solved it. See [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18974) GitHub issue for more details.

However, they don't provide a resolution that works for everyone, and no solution for Vue. I've had some issues with IonMenu as well, so I figured I'd take a crack at the problem.

I modified your code, and it works in my environment. The gist of it is that the menu remains disabled after switching routes, and it is complicated by animations. I added a computed `disabled` and `onBeforeRouteLeave` handlers. I only had success with both in play. This required menus to have a `menu-id`, and instead of making a bunch of props, I just used `provide()`. My changes are below.

`Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <Header />

    <IonContent :fullscreen="true">
      <span>Dashboard</span>
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {IonContent, IonPage, menuController} from "@ionic/vue";
import Header from "../components/Header.vue";
import {onBeforeRouteLeave} from "vue-router";
import {provide} from "vue";

const menuId = "dashboard-menu"
provide("menu-id", menuId)
provide("route-name", "dashboard")

onBeforeRouteLeave(async () => {
  await menuController.close(menuId)
  await menuController.enable(true, menuId)
})

</script>
```

`Profile.vue`

```
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <Header />
    <IonContent :fullscreen="true">
      <span>Profile Page</span>
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {IonContent, IonPage, menuController} from "@ionic/vue";
import Header from "../components/Header.vue";
import {onBeforeRouteLeave} from "vue-router";
import {provide} from "vue";

const menuId = "profile-menu"
provide("menu-id", menuId)
provide("route-name", "profile")

onBeforeRouteLeave(async () => {
  await menuController.close(menuId)
  await menuController.enable(true, menuId)
})

</script>

<style>
ion-modal {
  --height: auto;
}
</style>
```

`HeaderMenu.vue`

```
<template>
  <IonMenu side="end" :menu-id="menuId" content-id="main-content" :disabled="disabled">
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar color="primary"></IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent>
      <IonItemGroup>
        <IonList class="ion-no-padding">
          <IonMenuToggle>
            <IonItem class="ion-text-center">
              <IonButton
                expand="full"
                fill="clear"
                size="small"
                @click="navigate('dashboard')"
              >
                <span>Dashboard</span>
              </IonButton>
            </IonItem>
            <IonItem class="ion-text-center">
              <IonButton
                expand="full"
                fill="clear"
                size="small"
                @click="navigate('profile')"
              >
                <span>Profile</span>
              </IonButton>
            </IonItem>
          </IonMenuToggle>
        </IonList>
      </IonItemGroup>
    </IonContent>
  </IonMenu>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonMenu,
  IonMenuToggle,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonItemGroup,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import {computed, inject} from "vue";
import {useRouter} from "vue-router";

const routeName = inject("route-name")
const menuId: string = inject("menu-id")!
const router = useRouter()

const disabled = computed(() => {
  return router.currentRoute.value.name !== routeName
})

const navigate = (routeName: string) => {
  router.push({ name: routeName });
};
</script>

<style>
/* This fixes the issue with the menu not being clickable */
.menu-content-open {
  pointer-events: unset !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have see your code in HeaderMenu.vue page in IonToolbar component in set
your url and in defaultHref also set daynamic and static url(router).

ex:-

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
     <ion-back-button defaultHref="/" />
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

Header being a component common to both of your pages, standard practice would be to move it outside of both and have `<Header />` exist as a sibling just above `<ion-router-outlet />` in App.vue

In order to not have the header and page content overlap each other, the router component needs to be wrapped with `<IonContent>`

```html
<ion-app>
  <Header />
  <IonContent>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" />
  </IonContent>
</ion-app>
```

Doing just these two things fixes your issue.

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionmenu-forked-4zqxfp?file=/src/App.vue)